# Escape @ in Bitbucket issue descriptions

Tags: bitbucket

I have a project on Bitbucket which has to do with XPath expressions. That's why I often need to include the @ character into the description of my issues in the Bitbucket tracking system, followed by an identifier. Bitbucket, however, replaces every occurence of a @ sign followed by a user name with a link to that user.

How do I prevent Bitbucket from performing these substitutions, i.e. how do I escape the @ sign? I haven't found a word about this in the related sections of the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried `\@`?

Comment: I have but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to workaround the same problem by enclosing an expression in code syntax, using the backtick (`).

```
`book[/bookstore/@specialty=@style]`
```